# Nginx Error while sending HTTP Get Request in App Engine Flexible Enviroment

Tags: http, google-app-engine, nginx, go, google-app-engine-go

I am sending HTTP GET request in my App

When I send the request using `http.Get(URL)` just like the following code I get 200 as HTTP status code:

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://www.google.co.in/")
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
fmt.Fprintf(w, "HTTP GET returned status %v", resp.Status)
```

But if I use `http.NewRequest()` and `http.Client` just like the following code I get `502 Bad Gateway nginx` error

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.co.in/", nil)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
fmt.Fprintf(w, "HTTP GET returned status %v", resp.Status)
```

I checked Stackdriver log for `nginx.error` I see the following error

```
[error] 32#32: *6597 upstream prematurely closed connection while 
reading response header from upstream, client: $client_ip, server: , 
request: "GET /check HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://172.17.0.1:8080/check", host: "XXX.appspot.com"
```

I am new to App Engine and also I have limited knowledge of Nginx.

Comment: If you look at the [source for `Client.Get`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=12688:12748#L378), you'll see that it is exactly the same as calling `Client.Do`. You have something else going on which you haven't shown here.

Comment: @JimB There is nothing else going on I know this should work probably this is because of App Engine

Comment: You haven't shown how you're creating `client`, how is it different from `http.DefaultClient`? How is its Transport configured?